# Retrieve an element in a string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, element

I have a string in jQuery `$(elm).parent().parent().html()`.

This string return :

```
    <input name="formpage" value="formulaire_test" type="hidden">
<input name="postOK" value="accuse.html" type="hidden">
<input name="postNOK" value="erreur.html" type="hidden">
<input name="mailFrom" value="-1,-1,-1" type="hidden">
<input name="mailToName" value="Nom" type="hidden">
<input name="mailTo" value="a@a.fr" type="hidden">
<input name="mailSubject" value="Sujet" type="hidden">
<input value="name=mailText" type="hidden">
<div class="headerForm"><p>En tete</p></div>
<fieldset><legend>Nouveau</legend>
<div id="para0101" class="entry"><label for="id0101">sdf</label>
<input id="id0101" name="input0101" type="text"></div>
<div id="para0102" class="entry"><label for="id0102">sf</label>
<input id="id0102" name="input0102" type="text"></div>
<div id="para0103" class="entry"><label for="id0103">sfd</label>
<input id="id0103" name="input0103" type="text"></div></fieldset>
<div class="footer">pied form</div>
<div class="submit"><input value="annuler" type="reset">
<input value="envoyer" type="submit"></div>
```

How can i retrieve for example the value `En tete` in `<div class="headerForm">` ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".headerForm p",$(elm).parent().parent()).text();
```

this should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You need jquery class selector to access required element and use text method of jquery to get its text.

```
requiredvalue = $('.headerForm').text();
```

Comment: I can't, i need to start with $(elm).parent().parent().html(), i can't choose directly $('.headerForm')

Comment: Thanks you have to tell more, with which element you want to refer it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$(elm).parent().parent().find('.headerForm').text();

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = $('elm').parent().parent().html();
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
var $hdrFrm = $xml.find( "div.headerForm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
$(function () {
 var allHtml = $(elm).parent().parent().html();
 alert($(this).find('.headerForm p').html());
});
```